# Printing an array of objects using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a array of objects like below .

```
Signatures = [{
    "Name": "Person 1",
    "Status": "New"
}, {
    "Name": "Person 2",
    "Status": "New"
}, {
    "Name": "Person 3",
    "Status": "Completed"
}, {
    "Name": "Person 4",
    "Status": "Cancelled"
}];
```

I want to print the list by the "Name" of each of these objects in the following manner based on the Status.

```
New : Person 1 , Person 2
Completed : Person 3 
Cancelled : Person 4
```

I have tried doing that with 3 ng-repeats . each containing a ng-if for comparing whether the Status is New , Completed or Cancelled . But i am looking for a better solution . Thanks in advance for any help

here is the JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/21355/

Comment: Will you answer control and i gave the first answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify you dom to use filter

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div>
New 
  <span ng-repeat="signer in Signatures | filter : {Status : 'New'}">
      <span>
                  <b>{{signer.Name}}</b>
      </span>
  </span>
</div>

<div>
Completed 
  <span ng-repeat="signer in Signatures | filter : {Status : 'Completed'}">
      <span>
                  <b>{{signer.Name}}</b>
      </span>
  </span>
</div>

<div>
Cancelled 
  <span ng-repeat="signer in Signatures | filter : {Status : 'Cancelled'}">
      <span>
                  <b>{{signer.Name}}</b>
      </span>
  </span>
</div>

</div>
```

This will work as expected.

**[See jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p5gfp8Ln/)**

Answer (score 1):

Because *angular-1.0.1.js* not supported `ng-if`. You can use the `ng-hide` or `ng-show` .

AngularJS first added the ng-if directive in `1.1.5`.Please update the angular version.

```
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl">

    New: <span ng-repeat="signer in Signatures" ng-if="signer.Status=='New'">
      <b>{{signer.Name}}</b>
    </span>
    </br>
    Completed: <span ng-repeat="signer in Signatures" ng-if="signer.Status=='Completed'">
      <b>{{signer.Name}}</b>
     </span>
     </br>
    Cancelled: <span ng-repeat="signer in Signatures" ng-if="signer.Status=='Cancelled'">
          <b>{{signer.Name}}</b>
     </span>


 <div>
```

This will work as expected.

**[Example code.](http://jsfiddle.net/jackk88888/7eBWP/36/)**

Answer (score 1):

Simply try this code. This is working:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<span>New: </span>
<span ng-repeat="signer in Signatures|filter: { Status: 'New' } ">
    <span ng-if="signer.Status=='New'">
        <b>{{signer.Name}}</b>
    </span>
</span>
<br />
<span>Completed: </span>
<span ng-repeat="signer in Signatures|filter: { Status: 'Completed' } ">
    <span ng-if="signer.Status=='New'">
        <b>{{signer.Name}}</b>
    </span>
</span>
<br />
<span>Cancelled: </span>
<span ng-repeat="signer in Signatures|filter: { Status: 'Cancelled' } ">
    <span ng-if="signer.Status=='New'">
        <b>{{signer.Name}}</b>
    </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

As angular-1.0.1.js not supported ng-if, You can go by an another alternative method

```
angular.foreach(Signatures,function(value,key){
      if(value.Status=='New') {
           Signatures.pop(key);
      }
});
```